# three digit numbers such that the sum is not greater than 10 and no digit is zero

Tags: combinatorics

I have thought about this through starts and bars and want to know if my approach is correct: I have 12 stars and 3 bars assuming that the first digit cant be 0. Then I subtract the number of three digit numbers that have one or two zeros which is 171. so i get 49. Would appreciate if someone could let me know if this is the correct approach. Thanks!

Comment: Since no digit can be zero, why not consider three digit combinations consisting of the digits one through nine and ignore zero altogether?

Comment: You have up to 10 that you can distribute between the 3 digits. But each digit gets at least 1. This is the same as distributing up to 7 between 3 digits, where each digit gets at least 0.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another stars-and-bars approach:  As noted in the comments, each digit must be at least $1$. So count the number of solutions in non-negative integers of:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+y_4=7.$$

Here, $y_4$ is a slack variable equal to the difference between $10$ and the digit sum and $x_i$ is the difference between digit $i$ and $1$.

By stars-and-bars, there are $\binom{10}{3}=120$ solutions.  You appear to have overlooked solutions where the digit sum is strictly less than $10$.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good for you to also remember and use the simpler [Theorem1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:%7E:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.) stars and bars formula over positive integers, $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ where each bin contains a positive integer

So we add a *positive integer* slack variable $s$ to the equation to convert the inequation to an equation, and as we have added $1$ through the slack variable, we need to add $1$ on the right hand side, too.

$x_1+x_2+x_3+s = 11$ over the positive integers,
yielding answer $\dbinom{11-1}{4-1} = 120$